# SilverStripe: Getting "you need to change the ClassName before you can write it" after update files to use namespaces

Tags: exception, namespaces, silverstripe

I'm getting this exception when trying to ->write() a DataObject called 'ModelSheet', it says the name should be Models\ModelSheet instead of ModelSheet only (i am under the same namespace (Models) and even try with an use statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the ClassName saved to your database record does not match your PHP classname.

When changing classnames (adding or changing a namespace is changing the classname), you need to update the database to reflect this changes, as the classname is saved in the DB, so Silverstripe knows which PHP-Object is related to the data record.

If you used [Silverstripe's upgrader tool](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-upgrader), you should have an `.upgrade.yml` in your module's directory (e.g. in app or mysite). If not, you can add it manually (see e.g. https://github.com/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-onepage/blob/master/.upgrade.yml as a random example). The structure is like

```
mappings:
  OldClassName: My\Namespace\NewClassname
```

After that all you need is to run `dev/build/?flush` and your database should be updated.